# Avoid extra new line, writing on .txt file

Tags: java, nio

Currently I am using `java.nio.file.File.write(Path, Iterable, Charset)` to write txt file. Code is here...

```
    Path filePath = Paths.get("d:\\myFile.txt");
    List<String> lineList =Arrays.asList("1. Hello", "2. I am Fine", "3. What about U ?");
    Files.write(filePath, lineList, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

[image]

But one more (4th) empty line generated in the text file. How can I avoid 4th empty line ?

```
1 | 1. Hello
2 | 2. I am Fine
3 | 3. What about U ?
4 |
```

Comment: IMHO, it is better to have the terminating newline than to leave it out. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline

Comment: I have got a good answer below. thanks. @Henry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From javadoc for write: "Each line is a char sequence and is written to the file in sequence **with each line terminated by the platform's line separator**, as defined by the system property line.separator."

Simplest way to do as you wish:

```
List<String> lineList =Arrays.asList("1. Hello", "2. I am Fine");
String lastLine = "3. What about U ?"; 
Files.write(filePath, lineList, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Files.write(filePath, lastLine.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: Seems this generates two files and first one (with two line) replaced by last one(one line). And finally I will get a file with only one line.

Comment: Oops... I forget to add open option. Fixed.

Comment: Yes ! this is, what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear @BorLaze . Can I append 2 or more `List<String> lineList;` one after another to my text file.  Like..  `Files.write(/*1st Line List*/);  Files.write(/*2nd Line List*/)  Files.write(/*3rd Line List*/)`

Comment: @M.A.Khomeni, why not? In the same way: `Files.write(filePath, lineList1, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND); Files.write(filePath, lineList2, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Check `Files.write` the code you call:

```
public static Path write(Path path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> lines,
                             Charset cs, OpenOption... options)
        throws IOException
    {
        // ensure lines is not null before opening file
        Objects.requireNonNull(lines);
        CharsetEncoder encoder = cs.newEncoder();
        OutputStream out = newOutputStream(path, options);
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, encoder))) {
            for (CharSequence line: lines) {
                writer.append(line);
                writer.newLine(); 
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

It creates new line at the end of each insert:

```
writer.newLine();
```

---

The solution is: provide data as `byte[]`:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("/Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/DEMOS/myFile.txt");
List<String> lineList =Arrays.asList("1. Hello", "2. I am Fine", "3. What about U ?");
String lineListStr = String.join("\n", lineList);
Files.write(filePath, lineListStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Oh ! yes it is. So, how can I avoid/remove this new line ?

Comment: @M.A.Khomeni please check it out, I think its a better solution

Comment: Yes, @Maxim Shoustin it is working fine, thanks. But I have too many lines about 500,000 with 1100 char each.

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
Files.writeString(filePath, String.join("\n",lineList), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```